# How to Update campaign in Bing Ads?

Tags: c#, ads, bing, bing-api

For Update campaign I am using this Code

```
public async Task<List<long?>> updateCampaign(Campaign campaign,string status)
    {
        try
        {
            campaign.Status = (CampaignStatus)(int)Enum.Parse(typeof(CampaignStatus), status);
            var request = new UpdateCampaignsRequest
            {
                Campaigns = new Campaign[] { campaign },
                CustomerId = "xxxxxx",
                UserName = "something@outlook.com",
                Password = "something@123",
                ApplicationToken = "myApplicationToken",
                CustomerAccountId = "123456",
                DeveloperToken = "1234567890"
            };

            CampaignService = new ServiceClient<ICampaignManagementService>(_authorizationData);
            CampaignService.RefreshOAuthTokensAutomatically = false;
            var result = (await CampaignService.CallAsync((s, r) => s.UpdateCampaignsAsync(r), request));

            if (result.TrackingId != null)
            {
                return result.CampaignIds.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return new List<long?>();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLog.log(ex);
            return new List<long?>();
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, I got this error "Invalid client data. Check the SOAP fault details for more information"

thanks.

Comment: See if this can help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab879ffa-110a-4e36-88f1-79bae367a5cb/updatekeywords-invalid-client-data?forum=BingAds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating the Campaign we can use "BulkServiceManager" for bulk updating of the campaign,you can use this service single campaign update also.

```
public async Task<List<long?>> updateCampaign(List<Campaign> campaigns)
    {
        try
        {
            var listBulkCampaign = new List<BulkCampaign>();
            foreach (var campaign in campaigns)
            {
              var _bulkCampaign = new BulkCampaign()
                {
                    Campaign = campaign
                };
                listBulkCampaign.Add(_bulkCampaign);
            }
            BulkServiceManager bulkServiceManager = new BulkServiceManager(_authorizationData);
            string fileName = bingCampaignUpdate.csv;
            var campaigns = (await bulkServiceManager.UploadEntitiesAsync(new EntityUploadParameters
            {
                Entities = listBulkCampaign,
                OverwriteResultFile = true,
                ResultFileDirectory = FileDirectory,
                ResultFileName = fileName,
                ResponseMode = ResponseMode.ErrorsAndResults
            })).OfType<BulkCampaign>().ToList();

            return new List<long?>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLog.log(ex);
            return new List<long?>();
        }
}
```

You have to download .csv report and update the Campaigns.

I hope it helps you

Comment: you have advised to download .csv report to update the campaigns.  Would another route be to use DownloadEntitiesAsync if you wanted to avoid using the file system? (oh, and by the way, my issue is similar but requires updating Ad Groups across many campaigns.  I'm assuming your example code could be used with the BulkAdGroup type.